# How to test code inside setInterval with jest.useFakeTimers()

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Here is my simple code myClass.js:

```
class myClass {
  functionOne() {
    setInterval(() => {
      const age = 10
      try {
        const userName = "John Smith"

        console.log(`Name: ${userName}, age: ${age}`)

      } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error', error)
      }
    }, 5000)
  }
}
module.exports = new myClass()
```

I'm trying to test it with JEST that works fine:

```
const myClass = require('./myClass')

test("test one", () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();

  myClass.functionOne();
  expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 5000);

  jest.clearAllTimers();
});
```

Expects work fine and test pass. But sonar-scanner report says that the code inside setInterval() not covered by tests. So how do I really test code inside setInterval?

Comment: Thank you Mr. ggorlen.. But that answer related to React.JS.. Not sure how I can apply that to my code above

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can spy on `console.log` method and assert if it has been called or not. Besides, your example code will never throw an error, which means the `catch` statement block will never execute.

E.g.
`myClass.js`:

```js
class myClass {
  functionOne() {
    setInterval(() => {
      const age = 10;
      try {
        const userName = 'John Smith';
        console.log(`Name: ${userName}, age: ${age}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error', error);
      }
    }, 5000);
  }
}

module.exports = new myClass();
```

`myClass.test.js`:

```js
const myClass = require('./myClass');

describe('61902581', () => {
  test('test one', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    myClass.functionOne();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('Name: John Smith, age: 10');
    expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 5000);

    jest.clearAllTimers();
    logSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61902581/myClass.test.js (10.621s)
  61902581
    ✓ test one (30ms)

  console.log
    Name: John Smith, age: 10

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |      90 |      100 |     100 |      90 |                   
 myClass.js |      90 |      100 |     100 |      90 | 9                 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.718s
```

Comment: thank you Mr. slideshowp2.. It works perfect. .An yes I know catch won't be executed. That was just simple file I put here so you have a general idea of my service.